# why http_proxy,https_proxy,all_proxy env didn't work For me when i use git proxy?

Tags: git, proxy, http-proxy, env

Now I need to clone some repositorys,but They are banned,then I read some words from https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html:

> http.proxy
>
> Override the HTTP proxy, normally configured using the http_proxy, https_proxy, and
> all_proxy environment variables (see curl(1)). This can be overridden on a per-remote basis; see remote..proxy

Then I set the three env virables:

```
export all_proxy="domain.com:8888"
export http_proxy="domain.com:8888"
export https_proxy="domain.com:8888"
```

But It didn't work,then I reset them to "",then i set http.proxy use this:

```
git config --local http.proxy "domain.com"
```

It works.But I shouldn't set global,because there may be others are cloning but they shouldn't use proxy,and why It didn't work by set that three env virables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either because you set the env to `domain.com:8888` and did not specify a port in the git config, or because you need to uppercase those env vars.

Also you do realize, that you can set git vars per repo? So you could do:

```
git init myrepo
cd myrepo
git config http.proxy "domain.com"
git remote add origin myremote
git fetch --all
git checkout -B master origin/master
```

And then only this repo would you the proxy.

Comment: Is there a method that I can specify a proxy when I am cloning a spedific repository?

Comment: Not with pure git. You could write a wrapper script to handle that.

Comment: Clad I could help, but what exactly was the issue with the env vars?

Answer (score 1):

You can (at least now) also pass the proxy setting together with the clone command:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/repository.git --config "http.proxy=host:port"
```